# Excel: Condition to check multiple cells and return result

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to find an excel formula for my case. Context:

Users from a company receive and surrender IT assets daily. I need a formula that searches for the serial number of the it asset and checks if it has been returned when users leave the company. The thing is that the user might go through several IT assets through their time in the company so the formula must check if he returned the last item provided to him.

The structure of the sheets is something like this:

Sheet 1: provided assets 
User A | Laptop SN | Date: October 12th 2020|
User A | 2nd Laptop SN | Date: 24th May 2021

Sheet 2: returned assets 
User A | Laptop SN | Date: 24th May 2021

In this case, the formula should return false as he only returned one laptop when he received a new one.

So it should check if the all the serial numbers assigned to an user in the first sheet “provided” are found in the second sheet “returned”, basically, and return true or false.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code/homework writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code/calculations you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'd suggest to rearrange "the database", make all data be on a single Sheet & Row in a single Excel file; place the asset serial number in the first column, the take notes in the cell to the right of it. Then you do not need any formula.

Comment: Databases are a good thing. Table for each asset type, table for the user, and a transaction table that shows actions involving check outs of equipment to users and checkins of the same. This allows reports showing any movements and when they happened, as well as equipment with a checkout but no checkin.

Comment: COUNTIF function to check if the laptop SN is existed in the first sheet?